# Method won't return some values, but will return others

Tags: c#, winforms, methods, count

I have the following method which returns a number:

```
public int basketContents()
{
    int basketContains = basket.Count();
    return basketContains;
}
```

If I run this method in Main it works fine, however when I use it in a different form in the project it returns 0, regardless of what the actual number should be.

I've called it in the other form like this:

```
Main Main = new Main();

MessageBox.Show("Basket Contents: " + Main.basketContents(), "Information",
MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk);
```

If I set 'basketContains' to a number myself it will display the number fine in either form. However, when I use the count method it doesn't work.

Comment: Put a breakpoint in that method and debug it

Comment: What is `basket`, where is it defined, where is it populated, and what makes you sure it has non-zero contents?

Comment: Its an generic list. Im sure it has contents because Im using the same method in Main which shows the contents, though it always says 0 when using it in the other form

Answer (score 1):

I guess `basket` is not static. So in this case it will be null if you call it from another form, cause its a new variable with its default value (->empty so `Count` will be zero)

```
Main Main = new Main(); // Im a total new Form. I dont know anything, all my propertys are defaultvalues
```

Note: The answer is not "make it static". There a much better ways depending on your needs (f.e more parameters, events etc)

Example:

```
    public int basketContents(List<string> myBasket)
    {
     if (myBasket != null)
     {
        int basketContains = myBasket.Count();
        return basketContains;
     }
     return 0;
    }
```

call it:

```
Main mytest = new Main();
var temp = new List<string>();
temp.Add("test");

MessageBox.Show("Basket Contents: " + myTest.basketContents(temp), "Information");
```

Comment: Note, however, that this does not mean that the correct answer is "make it `static`"

Comment: Yes, sure, it was just the easiest way to explain. But i change it. Thanks

Comment: so how do i use the methods, etc. from another form?

Comment: @EmmetMcLaughlin i edited an example

Answer (score 0):

If basket is a member variable of class Main then you will need to set it after creating an instance of Main.

Also bad idea to call a variable the same name as a class.

Something like this should work:

```
Main myMain = new Main();
myMain.basket.Items.Add("Whatever");

MessageBox.Show("Basket Contents: " + Main.basketContents(), "Information",
MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk);
```